# Get all values with a certain key value

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

So I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and seem to be stuck. I have a multidimensionalarray and I'm trying to output all values with a certain key. Here is the code:

```
//My Array:
$services = array(
                array(  service_name => 'facebook', 
                    service_title => 'Facebook',
                    service_order => 0, 
                    service_type => 'Social Networking'
                    ),
                array(  service_name => 'twitter', 
                    service_title => 'Twitter',
                    service_order => 0,
                    service_type => 'Social Networking'
                    ),
                array(  service_name => 'tumblr', 
                    service_title => 'MySpace',
                    service_order => 0, 
                    service_type => 'Blogging'
                    )
);
```

The problem is I want to output the values by `service_type` for example "Social Networking" or "Blogging" I'm able to do this if I use a foreach statement like so:

```
 foreach($services as $service) {
    if ($service['service_type'] == 'Social Networking') {
             echo($service['service_title']);
    }
    if ($service['service_type'] == 'Blogging') {
             echo($service['service_title']);
    }
}
```

which works fine until I try to add a title in between types like

```
foreach($services as $service) {
    if ($service['service_type'] == 'Social Networking') {
             echo($service['service_title']);
    }
    echo ('<h3> Blogging</h3>');
    if ($service['service_type'] == 'Blogging') {
             echo($service['service_title']);
    }
}
```

I've learned enough to know that is because of the way `foreach` loops work so I've been trying to do this with something like `while($service['service_type'] == 'Social Networking')` (which creates a fun infinite loop) and various other ways.

Ideally I want to sort the array by `service_type` and then display the results without having to run the `foreach` loop in between headers.

Any help on this would be awesome or even other suggestions on ways to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
// Create an array containing all of the distinct "service types"
// from the $services array
$service_types = array();
foreach ($services as $service) {
    // If we have not yet encountered this entry's "service type",
    // then we need to add it to our new array
    if (!in_array($service['service_type'], $service_types)) {
        $service_types[] = $service['service_type'];
    }
}
if (count($service_types)) {
    // For each "service type", we want to echo a header and then
    // a list of services of that type
    foreach ($service_types as $current_type) {
        echo '<h3>'.$current_type.'</h3>';
        // Loop through the services and echo those that are
        // of the correct type
        foreach ($services as $service) {
            if ($service['service_type'] == $current_type) {
                echo($service['service_title']);
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo '<h3>No services</h3>'
}
```

Comment: Thanks that got me on the right track. I am getting this error though `Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument` Not sure what that means but I'll play with it a little bit. I would also love it if you could explain the code a little. I understand most of it but the more I understand the better.

Comment: _service_type_ should be quoted. `$service[service_type]` should be `$service['service_type']` on lines 3 and 4. Also, if you want to sort by service types, just add `sort($service_types);` after the first `foreach`.

Comment: I added some comments. I'm not sure why you would get that warning, the code looks correct at a glance.

Comment: I did that first but it seems that after asking my friend Google the problem was that `$service_types` isn't defined when the loop first runs so it was throwing a warning. I added `$service_types=array();` before the first `if` and it worked fine.

Comment: You missed one: `$service_types[] = $service['service_type']` :)

Comment: `$service_types[] = $service['service_type']` was the line having the error. (did you just add the `$service_types=array();` or did I miss that too?

Comment: @BandonRandon: `$service_types=array();` needs to come _before_ the foreach loop; otherwise, you'll be emptying the array on each iteration.

Comment: @Herbert yep got that now. Thanks :P

Comment: `$service_types = array();` was there from the start.

Comment: @BandonRandon: Happy to be of assistance... if I was. Hammerite did all the work. :)

Comment: @Hammerite, oh must have just missed it when I copied it over. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 12):

With php > 5.5 you can do

```
$myData = array(
    array(
        'service_name'  => 'facebook', 
        'service_title' => 'Facebook',
        'service_order' => 0, 
        'service_type'  => 'Social Networking'
    ),
    array(  
        'service_name'  => 'twitter', 
        'service_title' => 'Twitter',
        'service_order' => 0,
        'service_type'  => 'Social Networking'
    ),
    array(
        'service_name'  => 'tumblr', 
        'service_title' => 'MySpace',
        'service_order' => 0, 
        'service_type'  => 'Blogging'
    )
);

$filtered = array_column($myData, 'service_column');
```

see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: This is amazing.  Too bad I _just_ switched to 5.4 and it'll be a while before I get to use this.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I haven't followed all of your question, but you asked if you can sort the array by service type - so you can build a [user defined sorting function](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php).

```
function sortByServiceType($a, $b) {  
  // This will sort them by service type alphabetically
  return strcmp($a['service_type'], $b['service_type']);
}

uasort($services, 'sortByServiceType');
```